# Create a subclass of Rectangle in Python Zelle graphics

Tags: python, python-3.x, zelle-graphics

I'm trying to create a subclass of `Rectangle` in the Zelle graphics library in Python:

```
from graphics import*
win =GraphWin('tower of haoi',1000,600)
class DISC(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self,pt1,pt2,color):
        self.pt1=pt1
        self.pt2=pt2
        self.color=color
    def createdisc(self):
        self.setFill(self.color)
        self.draw(win)

disc1=DISC(Point(0,0),Point(28,10),color_rgb(230, 255, 245))
disc1.createdisc()
win.getMouse()
win.close()
```

But the created object doesn't accept any methods and gives the error:

```
AttributeError: 'DISC' object has no attribute 'config'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `DISC.__init__()` doesn't call the `__init__()` method of it's super class:

```
from graphics import *

class DISC(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, p1, p2, color):
        super().__init__(p1, p2)
        self.color = color

    def createdisc(self):
        self.setFill(self.color)
        self.draw(win)

win = GraphWin('Tower of Hanoi', 1000, 600)

disc1 = DISC(Point(0, 0), Point(28, 10), color_rgb(230, 255, 245))
disc1.createdisc()

win.getMouse()
win.close()
```

You don't need to store the two points in your object as you're already storing them because your object is a `Rectangle`.